# Matlab plotyy 4 plots with different LineStyle

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this Matlab code

```
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(step,a1,step,b1);
hold(ax(1))
plot(ax(1),step,a2)
hold(ax(2))
plot(ax(2),step,b2)
```

and the resulting plot is this

[image: matlab_plot]

where a2 and b2 are the smooth plots, and a1,b1 the other two. 
How can I get only a1 and b1 dashed?

Thanks

Comment: use set(h1,'LineStyle','--') and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since have already saved the handles to the line series of `a1` and `b1`, you can use

```
set(h1,'LineStyle','--');
set(h2,'LineStyle','--');
```

Similar, you can also change the color or add marker. For details please refer to [Matlab documentation.](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html)